# Can I pass my form values through jQuery .load() and make them readable by PHP $_POST?

Tags: php, jquery

Can I pass form values in load() function of jQuery then be able to read them as $_POST parameters in php? ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, add an object with the values as 2nd parameter to your load call. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) where is stated:

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

So your JavaScript could look like:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/call.php', { postVarName: 'value' }, function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

In PHP you can now access it:

```
echo $_POST["postVarName"]; // will echo: value
```

Comment: I just came from the docs before asking but I was a little confused..would appreciate a little example:)

Comment: Change test.html to test.php :)